# schema-registry in KAFKA not able to retrieve Cluster ID

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, confluent-schema-registry

I try to install a Kafka environment based on confluent images. After "docker-compose up" all my containers are up and running, but after one minute the schema-registry failed

[image]

in the scheme-registry log I found this error message explaining that it failed to get the Kafka cluster Id

[image]

I checked the kafka logs and found this :

> "[2021-08-05 15:59:17,074] INFO Cluster ID = ddchQ8odQM-hF67TJO97Ng (kafka.server.KafkaServer)"

So Cluster ID is well created. It seems that schema-registry is not able to retreive the Cluster ID but I really don't understand what happen here, I think it is a network issue, I tried many things to fix it but whithout success

here my docker-compose.yaml

```
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    #    networks:
    #      - my-network
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    deploy:
      resources:
          limits:
            cpus: "1.00"
            memory: "1024M"

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
        #    networks:
        #      - my-network
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
      - 30001:30001
    environment:
#     KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: toto
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 100
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 30001
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: kafka
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
    deploy:
      resources:
          limits:
            cpus: "1.00"
            memory: "2048M"

  kafka-jmx-exporter:
    build: ./materials/tools/prometheus-jmx-exporter
    container_name: jmx-exporter
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    links:
      - kafka
        #    networks:
        #      - my-network
    environment:
      JMX_PORT: 30001
      JMX_HOST: kafka
      HTTP_PORT: 8080
      JMX_EXPORTER_CONFIG_FILE: kafka.yml
    deploy:
      resources:
          limits:
            cpus: "1.00"
            memory: "1024M"

  prometheus:
    build: ./materials/tools/prometheus
    container_name: prometheus
    #    networks:
    #      - my-network
    ports:
      - 9090:9090

  spark-master:
    container_name: spark-master
    build: ./materials/spark
    user: root
    #    networks:
    #      - my-network
    volumes:
      - ./materials/spark/connectors:/connectors
      - ./materials/spark/scripts:/scripts/
      - ./materials/consumer:/scripts/consumer
      - ./secrets:/scripts/secrets
      - ./materials/spark/jars_dir:/opt/bitnami/spark/.ivy2:z
    ports:
      - 8085:8080
      - 7077:7077
      - 4040:4040
    environment:
      - INIT_DAEMON_STEP=setup_spark
    deploy:
      resources:
          limits:
            cpus: "1.00"
            memory: "1024M"
      # - SPARK_MODE=master
      # - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      # - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      # - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      # - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no

  spark-worker-1:
    container_name: spark-worker-1
    build: ./materials/spark
    user: root
    #    networks:
    #      - my-network
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    ports:
      - 8083:8085
      - 4041:4040
    environment:
      - "SPARK_MASTER=spark://spark-master:7077"
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark-master:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1G
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
    deploy:
      resources:
          limits:
            cpus: "1.00"
            memory: "2048M"
          reservations:
            cpus: "1.00"
            memory: "1024M"

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry
    hostname : schema-registry
    container_name : schema-registry
    #command: /bin/sh -c 'tail -f /dev/null'
    command: /bin/schema-registry-start /etc/schema-registry/schema-registry.properties
    depends_on:
        - kafka
    ports:
        - 8081:8081
          #    networks:
          #        - my-network
    environment:
#       SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:29092
       SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka-1:9092
       SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
       SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081
       SCHEMA_REGISTRY_DEBUG: "true"
       SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE.INIT.TIMEOUT.MS: 120000

    deploy:
      resources:
           limits:
             cpus: "1.00"
             memory: "2048M"

  producer:
    build: ./materials/producer
    container_name: producer
    depends_on:
      - kafka
        #    networks:
        #      - my-network
    environment:
        KAFKA_BROKER_URL: kafka-1:9092
        TRANSACTIONS_PER_SECOND: 30

  kafkastream:
    build: ./materials/kafkastream
    container_name: kafkastream
    depends_on:
      - kafka
        #    networks:
        #      - my-network
    environment:
            KAFKA_BROKER_URL: kafka-1:9092
            TRANSACTIONS_PER_SECOND: 5

  rest-proxy:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - schema-registry
        #    networks:
        #      - my-network
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    hostname: rest-proxy
    container_name: rest-proxy
    #command: /bin/kafka-rest-start
    environment:
        KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: rest-proxy
        KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:29092
        KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8082
        KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081


#networks:
    #my-network:
  #        external: false
        # my-network:
```

My last try was to completly remove the network in the docker-compose file, that is why all the lines related to networks are commented here.

Any hint or idea will be appreciate

Thanks

Comment: Can other applications connect to Kafka?

Comment: Yes I succeeded to create a producer and a consumer without problems, and they work fine with kafka container

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution. My mystake was to add the following line in my docker-compose.yml file : "command: /bin/schema-registry-start /etc/schema-registry/schema-registry.properties". In that way, schema-registry start by taken into acount the default configuration of the schema-registry.properties file that is of course not suitable to my local installation and ignore all the environment parameter passed in the docke-compose.yaml file.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you should not set command at all and the image automatically start the service, can you update with your final working setting?

Comment: Yes right, that's what I did I just remove "command:" line in my docker-compose.yml and it works now. So my final working settings is exactly the same than the yml file attach to this post, except the "command: " line that has been removed.

Answer (score 0):

PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092 , change to kafka-1 or use kafka:29092

Comment: thanks Ran I nerver tried this, I will do and keep you informed

Comment: Hi Ran, I tried what you propose but it didn't fix my problem. Nevertheless I found the solution.